# View powerpoint online while prevent users from saving it

Tags: security, microsoft-powerpoint

My company currently has a number of powerpoint-based trainings. While we want these to be accessible and viewable by our client, we do not wish for our client to be able to distribute the material. While we have expressed the need to keep the material private and applied the appropriate markings, there has been at least one occasion in the past through a simple mistake, the material landed in the hands of one of our competitors. Because it's a large client, we're hesistant to rock the boat.

My current thought is to host the powerpoints on our site, accessible only by those who have a login and that the site makes it more difficult take a screen capture or to save the page source (I get this isn't a full-proof solution, but will geatly limit the number of people able to download the training material.

Are there any good alternatives? Or different ways to implement something like this?

Comment: Well, anyone who wants could just take a screenshot (hit the PrntScrn key) and get a copy of your work. You could, if you are very serious about this, embed a flash object (some .swf) that holds and presents your powerpoint presentation. I've seen this and getting the original file is more than just complicated. With one-time access tokens per request you could protect your setup against replay attacks and encrypting everything will make it just more complicated. It sounds complicated but it's rather simple to implement this using a database, some php scripts and that flash script.